# Laravel: This cache store does not support tagging with array or redis

Tags: laravel, caching, composer-php

I am getting the following error on my Laravel application :

```
BadMethodCallException
This cache store does not support tagging.
```

But, in my .env I have set `CACHE_DRIVER=array` or `redis`.

I am unable to use [spatie/laravel-responsecache](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-responsecache) because of this issue.

Reinstalling my application didn't help.

Maybe a package is interfering with my app, but the problem is new. Here is my `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.9",
    "felixinx/gtfs-realtime-protobuf-php": "@dev",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
    "laravel/horizon": "^3.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "league/csv": "^9.1",
    "mad-web/laravel-initializer": "^2.0",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "~4.0",
    "spatie/laravel-responsecache": "^6.3",
    "symfony/psr-http-message-bridge": "^1.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
},
```

Comment: According to the README, the environment variable should be `RESPONSE_CACHE_DRIVER`, also make sure to clear the config cache.

Comment: @Razor this is the good answer! It's weird that I didn't had to use this variable before...

Comment: yeah that's weird, you were probably using an old version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the `RESPONSE_CACHE_DRIVER` environment variable:

```
RESPONSE_CACHE_DRIVER=array|redis|memcached
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `cache_tag` on your `config/responsecache.php` file.

```
     /*
     * If the cache driver you configured supports tags, you may specify a tag name
     * here. All responses will be tagged. When clearing the responsecache only
     * items with that tag will be flushed.
     *
     * You may use a string or an array here.
     */
    'cache_tag' => '',  // <-- make sure this is empty
```

If it's already empty, try setting it to `false` or `null`. Hope it helps!

Comment: It is empty, but the goal is to use cache tag!

Answer (score 0):

Using the php artisan optimize:clear command worked for me.  It clears everything, I'm guessing clearing config cache would be enough.